# Does C++ calls member object 's overloaded operator?

Tags: c++

```
 #include <stdio.h>

 class InnerOne {
     int m_iDummy;
     public:
     InnerOne(int iDummy) {
         m_iDummy=iDummy;
     }   

     InnerOne& operator=(InnerOne &obj) {
         printf("In InnerOne Operator=\n");
         m_iDummy = obj.m_iDummy;
         return *this;
     }   

 };  

 class OuterOne {
     InnerOne m_innerOne;
     public:
     OuterOne(int iVal) : m_innerOne(iVal) {
     }   

 };  

 int main() {
     OuterOne a(1);
     OuterOne b(2);
     a = b;
     return 1;
 }
```

Will InnerOne 's operator = get called?
If yes then how and why?

Comment: Compile and try out?! We're not your personal compiler. If you don't have access to one currently, try [Ideone](http://ideone.com).

Comment: As an aside, your main() function should return an int.

Comment: Please do not add line numbers to your code - it prevents it being easily copied and compiled.

Comment: Is this guaranteed? I though if neither a = operator or copy constructor was declared in OuterOne then it could do a bitwise copy instead. This was meant for the answer bellow.

Comment: The default copy constructor always does a memberwise copy

Comment: "As an aside, your main() function should return an int." It does now, but it returns 1. Not a good idea. SunnyShah: Return 0, not 1. Returning a non-zero value means that your program ran to completion but it did not do so successfully, where the meaning of "successful" is up to the programmer.

Comment: @Xeo: Just because something works on one compiler/platform, it doesn't mean that it is well-defined behavior. This is a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The compiler generated copy-assignment for `OuterOne` will invoke the `operator=` for `InnerOne`.

As a sidenote, its better if you write `InnerOne` copy-assignment as:

```
InnerOne& operator=(const InnerOne &obj)
                  //^^^^ add this!
```

`const` is necessary, or else your code wouldn't work for the following:

```
const InnerOne x(10);
InnerOne y(10);

y = x; //compilation error - if you use your code
```

See the error here : http://www.ideone.com/YMTJS

And once you add `const` as I suggested, it'll compile. See this : http://www.ideone.com/xj06z

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The automatically generated assignment operator for `OuterOne` will call the assignment operator of `InnerOne`.

Comment: Is this guaranteed? I though if neither a = operator or copy constructor was declared in OuterOne then it could do a bitwise copy instead. i.e implementation defined.

Comment: @eyesathousand: It would only do a bitwise copy if OuterOne was a POD type. Since InnerOne has an overloaded assignment operator, it is not a POD, and OuterOne is therefore also not a POD since it contains a non-POD member.

Comment: @eyesathousand: If this was not guaranteed, you would be forced to implement `operator=` for any type that contains an object that itself implements `operator=`. I.e. `struct test { std::string name; }; test a = {"Hi"}, b = {"there"}; a = b;` would be incorrect.

Comment: Well, C++ isn't quite as dangerous as I thought in that case. I always code defensively in C++ anyway - I always create copy constructors and operator=, even though it now seems I don't have to.